# Can I use the helping verb "had" instead of "has" in the Perfect Tense when talking about the present period of time?

Tags: perfect-aspect

When I talk about a period of time that hasn't finished yet (at the moment of speaking), can I use the helping verb "had" instead of "has" in the Perfect Tense?

For example, should I still say:

> By the end of this academic year she **has** really changed a lot, having
>   turned from a quiet student to one of the most talkative ones in this
>   class.

or I can also say:

> By the end of this academic year she **had** really changed a lot, having
>   turned from a quiet student to one of the most talkative ones in this
>   class.

?

Comment: If the end of the academic year hasn't come yet, you have to say _she will have changed_; but it's more logical to say _During the current academic year she has changed_.

Comment: @KateBunting: So, can I say "had" or not?

Comment: Only if you are speaking _after_ the end of the academic year.

Comment: @KateBunting - I see. Thank you.